# Why can't I call showA() using A's object?

Tags: c++, scope-resolution-operator

Why are we able to call the showA() method without object? But if I use void A::showA(A& x) in the method definition then I have to call it using A's object, why?

```
#include <iostream> 

class A { 

public:
    int a;
    A() { a = 0; } 


     void showA(A&); 
}; 

void showA(A& x) 
{ 

    std::cout << "A::a=" << x.a; 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    A a; 
    showA(a); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why are we able to call the `showA()` method without object?

You don't call the member function `A::showA`, but instead the *free* function `showA`. In fact, the member function `A::showA(A&)` is declared, but never defined, only the free function `showA(A&)` has a definition.

If you want to call `A::showA`, you need a definition;

```
void A::showA(A& x) { /* ... */ }
//   ^^^ this makes it a member function definition
```

and then call it as

```
A a;

a.showA(a);
```

(Note that it doesn't make much sense to pass the `a` instance to `A::showA` invoked on the identical `a` instance, but that's another issue).

Answer (score 1):

This function

```
void showA(A& x) 
{ 

    std::cout << "A::a=" << x.a; 
}
```

is not a member function of the class `A`.

It accepts one argument of the type `A &`.

As for the member function `showA` then it is declared but not defined.

You could declare it within the class like

```
class A { 

public:
    int a;
    A() { a = 0; } 


     void showA() const; 
};
```

and then define it outside the class definition like

```
void A::showA() const
{ 

    std::cout << "A::a=" << a; 
}
```

In this case the function main can look like

```
int main() 
{ 
    A a; 
    showA(a); 
    a.showA(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call it because showA(the one you are thinking) is not the part of the class.It is a global function.The showA function which you declared in class was never defined. In order to do so  modify your code a bit.
Change this piece of code.

```
void A::showA(const A& x) { 
std::cout << "A::a=" << x.a; }  // It is advised to make const as it doesn't change state.
```